# Getting ProtoGen with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, nuget, protobuf-net

I'm trying to serialize some classes with protobufs. I installed protobuf-net using NuGet, properly decorated my code with the attributes, and everything is running great.

However, eventually messages will be created in C#, but consumed in other environments, so I need to either create .proto files from C#, or - what seems more reasonable to me - create C# code from .proto files.

No matter what I do, I can't find ProtoGen.exe installed anywhere in my computer. I also found [this old post](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/07/protobuf-net-now-with-added-orcas.html), but nothing of the sort happens when I create a .proto text file. Adding ProtoBufTool manually didn't work, either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Protogen is included in the v1/280 build, or there is a separate VS tool available from the project site. There isn't a convenient way to include it in nuget in any sensible way (I checked with MS folks; twice).

For both protogen and the VS addin, the functionality has not changed for v2, so the existing v1 binaries remain fine for use with v2.

If the ProtoBufTool didn't work then... I don't know what is up with that; was there any error message / warning? The classic warning is about the input file's encoding ("protoc", google's tool, is very fussy about encoding).

Comment: I tried v2, which explains why nothing happens (the tool didn't even run, there was no error whatsoever). I'll try getting it from v1. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, just a quick one: is this information up to date? I.e. is the tool included in nuget now and installs properly? I am not sure about the "right" way to get protogen as of 2017, since the [GitHub page](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net#proto-file) only redirects to a rather old blog post, which doesn't provide any additional links.

Comment: @Groo the easiest way to get that today is http://protogen.marcgravell.com - it is available as source, but I have work to do on packaging it for nuget