# Protobuf-net and .proto file?

Tags: java, .net, wcf, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm going to use protobuf-net library with my WCF services. Clients is Java-Android and I work with proto files on that side.

Should I manually code classes on .NET side or protobuf-net somehow supports .proto files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are working from interop, then starting from .proto is the best option. For protobuf-net, there is a command-line tool "protogen", and a VS IDE add-in, that allow you to create protobuf-net compatible classes from .proto, similar to how you generate the code for other platforms. Both are available on the protobuf-net project site. If you already have classes, there is also some support for generating .proto from protobuf-net classes, but this is incomplete (indeed, in terms of v2 I only wrote it last night, so it is not in an official download yet).

If you are using cross-platform, you might also want to consider protobuf-csharp-port. This is a separate and parallel implementation by Jon, which retains a similar API to the Java API. You might find having a similar API between platforms to be be convenient.

Comment: Marc, Is there any rough estimate on when POCO->.proto will be official? I'm migrating from JSON so I have on C# side - POCO, on Android side - POJO :) Now on Android to work with proto I _have_ to create .proto file. I like how protobuf-net works and now I either need to generate classes from .proto so they match or manually edit POCO's I have already (which seems like nono)

Comment: @katit I *literally* wrote the first cut of v2 GetProto/GetSchema last night. What it needs is a: more testing by me, and b: a bit of "does it work in the wild" by a.n.other. You're welcome to give it a go and let me know about any problems you find. Confidence comes from evidence, if you see what I mean...

Comment: I started to use protogen but command line was failing and then I finally got VS integration working but to make it work I need to reference older protobuf-net.dll and switch it back after regenerate? Ideally I'd like to keep 1 shared .proto file for my development. Yes, I'd like to help you test it!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interoperating with Java, you shouldn't write .NET classes -- instead, you should generate C# classes from the .proto files.

I haven't used protobuf-net (although I've used the Java protobuf extensively), but [supposedly there's a Visual Studio tool](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/07/protobuf-net-now-with-added-orcas.html) to automatically generate C# code from .proto files.  There is also apparently a command line tool, but [it seems that may not always be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079783/getting-protogen-with-protobuf-net).