# protobuf-net: deserialise extend keyword to inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c#, inheritance, protobuf-net

I have a specific use-case for inheritance using protobuf-net which I haven't found is covered here yet (although happy to be redirected to any answers that would be useful).

I have to deserialise some objects from a third-party protobuf feed (GTFS-RT), and the .proto that has been supplied uses the `extend` keyword to extend the base types (which we also use with other feeds), which seems sensible from an objective point of view.  However, I cannot get protobuf-net to deserialise the feeds in this format into an appropriate inheritance hierarchy.

For example, the base .proto defines a `FeedHeader` (under a package called `transit_realtime`):

```
message FeedHeader {
  required string gtfs_realtime_version = 1;

  enum Incrementality {
    FULL_DATASET = 0;
    DIFFERENTIAL = 1;
  }
  optional Incrementality incrementality = 2 [default = FULL_DATASET];

  optional uint64 timestamp = 3;

  extensions 1000 to 1999;
}
```

The third-party extends `FeedHeader` to include another property:

```
extend transit_realtime.FeedHeader {
 optional NyctFeedHeader nyct_feed_header = 1001;
}
```

I would like to deserialise this into the following class hierarchy:

```
namespace Base.GTFS 
{
    [ProtoContract(Name = nameof(FeedHeader))]
    public class FeedHeader
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, Name = nameof(gtfs_realtime_version), DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
        public string gtfs_realtime_version { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = false, Name = nameof(incrementality), DataFormat = DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
        [DefaultValue(Incrementality.FULL_DATASET)]
        public Incrementality incrementality { get; set; } = Incrementality.FULL_DATASET;

        [ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = false, Name = nameof(timestamp), DataFormat = DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
        [DefaultValue(default(ulong))]
        public ulong timestamp { get; set; } = default(ulong);

        public FeedHeader() { }

        #region Nested Enums
        [ProtoContract(Name = nameof(Incrementality))]
        public enum Incrementality
        {

            [ProtoEnum(Name = nameof(FULL_DATASET), Value = 0)]
            FULL_DATASET = 0,

            [ProtoEnum(Name = nameof(DIFFERENTIAL), Value = 1)]
            DIFFERENTIAL = 1
        }
        #endregion
    }
}

namespace Other.GTFS 
{
    [ProtoContract(Name = nameof(FeedHeader))]
    public class FeedHeader : Base.GTFS.FeedHeader
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// NYCT Subway extensions for the feed header
        /// </summary>
        [ProtoMember(1001, Name = nameof(nyct_feed_header), IsRequired = false, DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
        public NyctFeedHeader nyct_feed_header { get; set; } = null;

        public FeedHeader() : base() { }
    }
}
```

After reading through other posts here and elsewhere, I have tried to use the `AddSubType` methods, and `AddSurrogate` methods, but have found that I can only reliably have all fields deserialised if I override all of the fields in the base class.  This seems grossly inefficient, and will break if (and when) the base types change.  We also need to use serialise to the base types for other feeds, so I need a solution that will be easily extensible.

Does anyone know of any way to support this scenario, or have any suggestions that might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [proto2](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) `extend` and `extensions` keywords do not correspond to an inheritance hierarchy.  Rather, they more closely parallel the [`partial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) keyword in c#, allowing a message to be partially defined in one file with additions in another file.  From the [proto2 language documentation from Google](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions):

> Extensions let you declare that a range of field numbers in a message are available for third-party extensions. Other people can then declare new fields for your message type with those numeric tags in their own .proto files without having to edit the original file.

Thus, if I create the file `Question40863857_1.proto` containing:

```
package transit_realtime;

message FeedHeader {
  required string gtfs_realtime_version = 1;

  enum Incrementality {
    FULL_DATASET = 0;
    DIFFERENTIAL = 1;
  }
  optional Incrementality incrementality = 2 [default = FULL_DATASET];

  optional uint64 timestamp = 3;

  extensions 1000 to 1999;
}
```

And `Question40863857_2.proto` containing:

```
import "Question40863857_1.proto";

// Some random enum since the NyctFeedHeader type wasn't included in the question.
enum NyctFeedHeader {
    Value0 = 0;
    Value1 = 1;
}

extend transit_realtime.FeedHeader {
 optional NyctFeedHeader nyct_feed_header = 1001;
}
```

Then auto-generate a c# classes from them using protobuf-net's [`protogen.exe` utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079783/getting-protogen-with-protobuf-net) as follows:

```
protogen.exe -i:Question40863857_1.proto -i:Question40863857_2.proto
```

The resulting types are generated:

```
// Generated from: Question40863857_1.proto
namespace transit_realtime
{
  [global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"FeedHeader")]
  public partial class FeedHeader : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
  {
    public FeedHeader() {}

    private string _gtfs_realtime_version;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, Name=@"gtfs_realtime_version", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    public string gtfs_realtime_version
    {
      get { return _gtfs_realtime_version; }
      set { _gtfs_realtime_version = value; }
    }
    private transit_realtime.FeedHeader.Incrementality _incrementality = transit_realtime.FeedHeader.Incrementality.FULL_DATASET;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = false, Name=@"incrementality", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(transit_realtime.FeedHeader.Incrementality.FULL_DATASET)]
    public transit_realtime.FeedHeader.Incrementality incrementality
    {
      get { return _incrementality; }
      set { _incrementality = value; }
    }
    private ulong _timestamp = default(ulong);
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = false, Name=@"timestamp", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(default(ulong))]
    public ulong timestamp
    {
      get { return _timestamp; }
      set { _timestamp = value; }
    }
    private NyctFeedHeader _nyct_feed_header = NyctFeedHeader.Value0;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1001, IsRequired = false, Name=@"nyct_feed_header", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(NyctFeedHeader.Value0)]
    public NyctFeedHeader nyct_feed_header
    {
      get { return _nyct_feed_header; }
      set { _nyct_feed_header = value; }
    }
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"Incrementality")]
    public enum Incrementality
    {

      [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoEnum(Name=@"FULL_DATASET", Value=0)]
      FULL_DATASET = 0,

      [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoEnum(Name=@"DIFFERENTIAL", Value=1)]
      DIFFERENTIAL = 1
    }

    private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
    global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
      { return global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing); }
  }

}
// Generated from: Question40863857_2.proto
// Note: requires additional types generated from: Question40863857_1.proto
namespace Question40863857_2
{
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"NyctFeedHeader")]
    public enum NyctFeedHeader
    {

      [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoEnum(Name=@"Value0", Value=0)]
      Value0 = 0,

      [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoEnum(Name=@"Value1", Value=1)]
      Value1 = 1
    }

}
```

Notice there is NO inheritance hierarchy, just a single class `FeedHeader` with fields from both .proto files, along with with the ancillary enums.

In fact, if you have a complete set of .proto files, you can use `protogen.exe` to generate your c# types for you thus avoiding this difficulty.  Or, use the [plugin](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2009/07/protobuf-net-now-with-added-orcas.html) for visual studio.

Conversely, if you need to check if the contract specified by a c# type `T` matches a required .proto file, you can do:

```
Console.WriteLine(RuntimeTypeModel.Default.GetSchema(typeof(T)));
```

For `typeof(Other.GTFS.FeedHeader)` this results in:

```
message FeedHeader {
   optional NyctFeedHeader nyct_feed_header = 1001 [default = Value0];
}
enum NyctFeedHeader {
   Value0 = 0;
   Value1 = 1;
}
```

Which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I figured that this is pretty much how it works.  It is a shame, since I have a service layer that sits on top of these which declares an interface that uses the base classes - I think I will need to extract the required parts of the base model into interfaces, and ensure that they get applied to the partial generated classes (made easier seeing as they are partial).